# Why are my commits duplicating my username in latest commit message?

Tags: linux, git, github, version-control, terminal

I'm not exactly sure how I managed to do this but I went through my commits today and noticed something interesting.

It looks like GitHub is recognizing me as two separate people?

[image: It looks like GitHub is recognizing me as two separate people?]]

This is a personal repo and so far I'm the only person who has made any changes to the repo. I would like it to show just one name, I'm pretty new to Git/GitHub so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a link to the repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when your commit is authored by an email address that GitHub does not know about.

You can add this email to your GitHub account

(Click on your avatar > Settings > Email > Add email address)

...Or update your email in `~/.gitconfig` to match what you already have in GitHub.

```
[user]
   name = John Sprunger
   email = jsprunger@myemail.com
```